# Proving $RT\ln(a_i)$ equal to non PV work done by system,where $a_i$ is activity

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

First of all many here will might say that it is Chemistry question.If you think so then read [this article](http://web2.physics.miami.edu/~zuo/class/spr_14/Chemical%20potential.pdf) and then answer question.

Question is --- We know chemical potential is defined as $\mu_i =\mu_i^\textrm{standard}+RT\ln(a_i)$ . Here $a_i$ is activity of $i^\textrm{th}$ component of solution. In case of gases instead of $a_i$ it is $f_i$ that is fugacity of $i^\textrm{th}$ gas out of mixture of gases. Activity is here nothing but activity coefficient multiplied by concentration or in case of fugacity it is product of fugacity coefficient multiplied by partial pressure of gas.

But now this is not the only definition of Chemical potential. Chemical potential also means **partial molar Gibbs free energy** when pressure and temperature of system are constant. We know that Gibbs free energy of system at constant temperature and pressure also represents Non-PV work done by system. Now how can the term $RT\ln(a_i)$ can be correlated to Non-PV work done by system in order both two definitions will be equivalent.

Comment: So what's your question, specifically?

Comment: My question is How can we prove that the term $RTln(a_i)$ represents Non-PV work done by system?

Comment: "We know that Gibbs free energy of system at constant temperature and pressure also represents Non-PV work done by system": are you sure this is true? Isn't Gibb's free energy a state function and work a path function? I don't see how this can be true.

Comment: Of course I am sure about this and it can be readily proved.Almost every thermodynamic book contains that proof

Comment: Anyone please tell me if this is totally experimental to choose way of expressing concentration in activity term or can be proved.I didn't get answers to my question neither any attention